# django-admin sum multiple columns

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with several fields. And I wanted to add another field in django-admin (list_display), where it is the sum of all fields.

**Model's**

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    field2 = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    field3 = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    field3 = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    field4 = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**Model's Admin**

```html
class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Model1

    list_display = ('field1','field2',<!--Sum of (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5-->)

admin.site.register(Modell,Model1Admin)
```

i am using the last version of django.

Comment: what did you try until now

Comment: i am trying to do a def on admin file using a queryset to return the value i want , but until now , nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want you can do something like that:

1- Create a property in your model:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    field2 = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    field3 = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    field3 = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
    field4 = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def final_sum(self):
        return self.field1 + self.field2 + self.field3 + self.field4 + self.field5
```

2- Then use it in your admin.py

```
class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Model1

    list_display = ('final_sum', 'field1','field2', )

admin.site.register(Modell,Model1Admin)
```

Answer (score 1):

From Django admin docs regarding [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

There are four types of values that can be used in list_display:

....

A callable that accepts one argument, the model instance. For example:

```
def upper_case_name(obj):
    return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()
upper_case_name.short_description = 'Name'

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (upper_case_name,)
```

---

so in your case you can create method something like following

```
def field_sum(obj):
    attribute_list = [ 'field1','field2',...]
    return sum(getattr(obj, attribute) or 0 for attribute in attribute_list)

field_sum.short_description = 'Field sum'
```

Comment: that give a error "field_sum() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" , but i add 'self' on the def , and it is already working. thank you

Comment: the value that returns to me in my case is in thousands of euros, what will be the best strategy to present the result like xxx xxx,xx?

Comment: this is follow up question, do your research if you don't find answer post new question -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions